# How to create dropdown list dynamically using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do you create a dropdown list dynamically using jQuery?  By dropdown list, I mean a `<select>` with its associated `<option>` values.

Comment: `dropdown list`? did you mean the `<select>` tag?

Comment: Is it possible to provide a little more information?

Answer (score 84):

Just create the elements like any element.

Example:

```
var data = {
    'foo': 'bar',
    'foo2': 'baz'
}


var s = $('<select />');

for(var val in data) {
    $('<option />', {value: val, text: data[val]}).appendTo(s);
}

s.appendTo('body'); // or wherever it should be
```

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/dynamically-adding-dropdown-using-jquery/     - Above link is explaining how the above answer working step by step .. It will helpful. Just look into that. :)

Comment: in my case do as below... How do I append it to the newly added html element ? I mean s.appendTo ( what?)    var table = document.getElementById("demoGrid");
                var row = table.insertRow(1);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                
                cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' />" // I want dropdown list to be shown here for users to select

Comment: @singhswat: `s.appendTo(cell1)`.

Answer (score 10):

In its simplest form,

```
var opt = "<option> -- Select -- </option>";

$(opt).wrap('<select />');

$('#some-container-div').html(opt);
```

Answer (score 3):

http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-jquery-select-box-manipulation-plugin/