# Dynamically creating a select list from a collection in my model

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this in my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a.create').click(function () {
            // create dropdown, insert in span
        })
    });

</script>

<a class='create' href='#'>Click</a>
<span></span>
```

In my controller method, I'm passing in a collection that should populate the select list, and can be accessed in my view with `@Model.Agencies`.

I'm trying to follow the solution from here ([How to create dropdown list dynamically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814512/how-to-create-dropdown-list-dynamically-using-jquery)), but I don't know how to create an array from my model's collection.

Answer (score 0):

You basically just need to populate the JavaScript data array. This will require you inject the values into the array.

The outside `var data = {` and the foreach loop is generating the values based on the `@Model.Agencies`. Since I do not know how your `Agencies` list is defined, I just guessed, `Id` and `Name`

```
var data = {
     @foreach(var agency in Model.Agencies)
     {
       <text>'</text>agency.Id<text>': '</text>agency.Name<text>,</text>
     }    
}
```

You might have to play with the  tags.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using MVC, there are 2 other ways I can think of to do this.

The first is to use the HTML Helper functions `@Html.DropDownList()` or `@Html.DropDownList`. This is the easiest way and it will also submit the value attribute of the selected option back to your viewmodel. To use these functions, you'll need to make the list a SelectList or a list of SelectListItems.

The second way is to use extend the html helper. This takes more effort but may be necessary if you need to add custom attributes to the generated html.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create just Dropdown you can create like this

```
      @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AgencyId,
        new SelectList(Model.Agencies, dataTextField: "AgencyName", dataValueField: "FinancialYearId"))
```

And dropdown selected value you will get in AgencyId.