# I can't add new options to "select" element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have MVC application and there's a view with JavaScript code. I get data from service and return Json string (not object). Here'e the controller code:

```
public JsonResult GetDataTableAsJson()
{
    return Json(MobileServiceClient.GetAllCashdesks(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The JavaScript code in view:

```
$.ajax({

    ...

    html.push('<select id="options">');
    html.push('</select>');

    $.ajax({
        url: hostName + 'Search/GetDataTableAsJson',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: "true",
        async: false, 
        success: function (data1) {
            var dt = JSON.parse(data1);
            $.each(dt, function(key, value) {
                $('#options').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value.CityName).text(value.CityName));

        ...
```

What does it happen? The list is empty, but there should be items.

When I check "select" element inside second Ajax call:

```
var menu = document.getElementById("options");
```

The menu is null.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use this syntax in jQuery :           $('select#ddlid').prepend('<option value="0">--Select--</option>');

Comment: Simply, the "select" element is not visible from second Ajax call. Both Ajax calls are with: async: false.

Comment: try this

    $('select#ddlid').append('<option value="' + CityName.Value + '">' + CityName.Text +'</option>');

Comment: It doesn't work because the select" element can't be found.

Comment: refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814512/how-to-create-dropdown-list-dynamically-using-jquery

Comment: What is your variable `html`? What are you doing with it? You need to add your `select` to the document somehow, or $("#options") won't find it.

Comment: "html.push" adds HTML elements. The "select" is on the page after all, but at that moment code can't find it. I'm not sure why.