# How to dynamically generate a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php

In my php, I have created two dropdown or selection lists. My drop down list below:

```html
<select name="food">
    <option value="">...</option>
    <option value="Fruits">Fruits</option>
    <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
    </select>

<select name="type">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Lettuce">Lettuce</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="Tomato">Tomato</option>
    <option value="Carrots">Carrots</option>
    <option value="Mango">Mango</option>
  </select>
```

m one page to the next.

Comment: Did you Google your title?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create dropdown list dynamically using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814512/how-to-create-dropdown-list-dynamically-using-jquery)

Comment: @SamP not exactly what I am looking for. Those answers aren't very specific.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this using jQuery, but it will quickly become unmanageable in a large-scale app or website.

If you go this route, I would *avoid* using two different select boxes, as this will force you to choose two different names for the form POST, unless you use more jQuery hackery to remedy this problem.

My suggestion is to look at a lightweight JS framework. [Knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) has what you need.

[Look at this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4SseZ/1/).

```
var fruitOpts = ["Apple", "Orange", "Mango"];
var vegOpts = ["Lettuce", "Tomato", "Carrots"];

$("#food").change(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val === "") {
        return;
    }
    $("#type").find('option').not(':first').remove().end();

    $.each(val === "Fruits" ? fruitOpts : vegOpts, function (i, v) {
        $("#type").append("<option value=\"" + v + "\">" + v + "</option>");
    });

    $.each(val === "Fruits" ? vegOpts : fruitOpts, function (i, v) {
        $("#type").append("<option value=\"" + v + "\">" + v + "</option>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's version for two different php pages:

***1.php***

```
<script src="1.js"></script>
<a id='link' href='2.php'>go to another page</a>
<select id="food" name="food" onchange="selectFoodType()">
    <option value="">...</option>
    <option value="Fruits">Fruits</option>
    <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
    <option value="Berries">Berries</option>
</select>
```

***1.js***

```
function selectFoodType()
{
    var link = $('#link');
    var type = $('select#food option:selected').val();
    link.attr('href', link.attr('href') + '?type=' + type);
}
```

***2.php***

```
<script src="2.js"></script>
<select id='type' name="type" data-type='<?=$_GET['type']?>'>
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option data-type='Fruits' value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option data-type='Vegetables' value="Tomato">Tomato</option>
    <option data-type='Vegetables' value="Carrots">Carrots</option>
    <option data-type='Berries' value="Strawberry">Strawberry</option>
</select>
```

***2.js***

```
$(function() {
    var type = $('select#type').data('type');
    var itemsId = document.getElementById("type");
    var items = itemsId.getElementsByTagName("option");
    var selected_type = [], other_types = [];
    selected_type[0] = items[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < items.length; i++){
        if ($(items[i]).data('type') === type) {
            selected_type.push(items[i]);
            continue;
        }
        other_types.push(items[i]);
    }
    selected_type = selected_type.sort(sortByName);
    other_types = other_types.sort(sortByName);
    $.merge(selected_type, other_types);
    var list = '';
    for (i=0; i<selected_type.length; i++) {
        list += selected_type[i].outerHTML;
    }
    $(items).remove();
    $(itemsId).append(list);
});

function sortByName(a, b) {
    if (a.text > b.text) return 1;
    else if (a.text < b.text) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign all `Fruits` and `Vegetables` contents in `JavaScript` object  and display related contents of `food` value in another drop down, see below demo

```
Food: 
 <select name="food" id="food">
   <option value="">...</option>
   <option value="Fruits">Fruits</option>
   <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
 </select>
Content 
 <select name="contents" id="contents">
  <option value="">...</option>
 </select>
```

JS code

```
var data = {
   'Fruits':['Apple', 'Lettuce', 'Orange', 'Mango'], 
   'Vegetables': ['Tomato', 'Carrots']
};

document.getElementById("food").onchange = function(Event){
    var contents = document.getElementById("contents");
    contents.innerHTML = "";
    for(var i in data[this.value]){
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute('value',data[this.value][i]);
        option.text = data[this.value][i];
        contents.appendChild(option);
    }
    var expect_data = Event.target.value == "Fruits" ? "Vegetables" : "Fruits";
    for(var i in data[expect_data]){
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.setAttribute('value',data[expect_data][i]);
        option.text = data[expect_data][i];
        contents.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>FIDDLE DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Mjfb8/3)

Comment: Nice! But I think he still wants to display the option not selected for some reason, just at the bottom of the list.

Comment: @SamP , i missed that, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use JQuery for this purpose.
See My Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/inventorx/YU4vJ/

Code Here:

HTML

```
<select name="food" >
<option value="">...</option>
<option value="Fruits">Fruits</option>
<option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
</select>

<select name='type' >
    <option>-- Select Food Type --</option>
</select>

<select id='Fruits' style='display:none' >
<option value="">--</option>
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
<option value="Mango">Mango</option>
</select>

<select id='Vegetables' style='display:none' >
<option value="">--</option>
<option value="Lettuce">Lettuce</option>
<option value="Tomato">Tomato</option>
<option value="Carrots">Carrots</option>
</select>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[name='food']").on("change", function(){
              var value = $(this).val();
              $("select[name='type']").html($("#" + value).html());
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option.

The list splits into two arrays: food, corresponding to the selected type; and does not correspond to the selected type. Each of these arrays, in turn, is sorted by name:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rxfJj/2/)

*HTML*:

```
<select id="food" name="food" onchange="selectFoodType()">
    <option value="">...</option>
    <option value="Fruits">Fruits</option>
    <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
    <option value="Berries">Berries</option>
</select>
<select id='type' name="type">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option data-type='Fruits' value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option data-type='Vegetables' value="Lettuce">Lettuce</option>
    <option data-type='Vegetables' value="Tomato">Tomato</option>
    <option data-type='Berries' value="Strawberry">Strawberry</option>
</select>
```

*JQuery*:

```
function selectFoodType()
{
    var type = $('select#food option:selected').val();
    var itemsId = document.getElementById("type");
    var items = itemsId.getElementsByTagName("option");
    var selected_type = [], other_types = [];
    selected_type[0] = items[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < items.length; i++){
        if ($(items[i]).data('type') === type) {
            selected_type.push(items[i]);
            continue;
        }
        other_types.push(items[i]);
    }
    selected_type = selected_type.sort(sortByName);
    other_types = other_types.sort(sortByName);
    $.merge(selected_type, other_types);
    var list = '';
    for (i=0; i<selected_type.length; i++) {
        list += selected_type[i].outerHTML;
    }
    $(items).remove();
    $(itemsId).append(list);
}

function sortByName(a, b) {
    if (a.text > b.text) return 1;
    else if (a.text < b.text) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This actually worked and you even added more values as well. I was wondering however, how can I implement this into two different php forms? What I mean is, the first drop down list is in one php page and the second drop down list is in another that comes after my first php.

Comment: Ok. I added the version for two different php pages