# Shortcode Dropdown WordPress - Text Editor Only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to add a shortcode dropdown onto the pure text editor in WordPress page editor next to the add media buttons.
I've seen a lot of questions relating to the dropdown, but they are all specifically for the tinyMce editor and **not the pure text editor**.

The visual editor has been disabled on my WordPress website but I would still like the users to be able to see all the shortcodes available.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the [Quicktags API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Quicktags_API) only accepts buttons, but we can trick the system with some jQuery as [it does all sort of things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/335333/1287812) ;)

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The shortcode dropdown is built from `var data` and its behavior should be ajusted `onchange`:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'quicktags_so_42200158' );

function quicktags_so_42200158() {
    if ( wp_script_is( 'quicktags' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        ?>
        <script>
        /* Button name and callback will be replaced */
        QTags.addButton( 'dummy_button', 'Dummy button', function(){} );

        jQuery(window).load( function() {
            jQ = jQuery;

            /* Build dropdown - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4814600 */
            var data = {
                '-': 'Select shortcode',
                'video': 'Video',
                'audio': 'Audio'
            }
            var s = jQ('<select />');
            s.attr('id','my-shortcodes');
            for(var val in data) {
                jQ('<option />', {value: val, text: data[val]}).appendTo(s);
            }

            /* Change 'Dummy button' for dropdown */
            jQ('#qt_content_dummy_button')[0].outerHTML = s[0].outerHTML;

            /* What will be inserted on HTML editor */
            jQ('#my-shortcodes').on('change', function(){
                var sc = '[' + jQ(this).val() + ']';
                QTags.insertContent(sc);
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

<sub>**Reference**: [*A Deeper Look Into the WordPress Text Editor*](https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-text-editor/)</sub>

Comment: Awesome answer thanks!! We ended up going another route but definitely something i will refer to in the future!